# For every normed space the norm map is not Fréchet differentiable at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

> Argue that for every normed space $\mathbb{X} \neq \{ 0 \}$ the norm map $\| \ldotp \|_\mathbb{X} : \mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not Fréchet differentiable at $0$.

Not really sure where to start on this question. I know the absolute value function is not Fréchet differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Consider a suitable map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{X}$, and recall that a composition of differentiable functions is differentiable.

Comment: So an inverse map?

Comment: No. Something simple that allows you to use what you already know.

Comment: Hmm something into $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: In the end, it can be shown as consequence of $\|{-}x\|=\|x\|$.

Comment: What are, apart from constant maps, the simplest maps $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{X}$ that you can think of?

Comment: Maybe the function $f(x)=x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were Frechet, then there would be a (bounded) linear operator $A$ so that
$$
\|v\|=A(v)+o(\|v\|).
$$
Now insert $-v$ and compare.

Comment: $\|-v\|=\|v\|=A(-v)+o(\|v\|).$   So $A(v)=A(-v)?$

Comment: Not exactly. $o(x)$ is a class of functions, so the consequence is $A(v)=o(\|v\|)$ which greatly reduces the class of linear maps that this applies to. -- You could also add so that $\|v\|+\|-v\|=o(\|v\|)$ which makes for a very degenerate norm.

Comment: Haven't really used the small oh notation. Is this the easiest way?

Comment: Then please add your definition of "Frechet differentiable" to the question. $r(v)=o(\|v\|)$ only means that $\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{r(v)}{\|v\|}=0$, i.e., it is a short notation for this limit.

Comment: $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-A_xh\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0\quad $

Comment: And as I said in the last comment, $f(x+h)-f(x)-A_xh=o(\|h\|)$ is an equivalent notation for that.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. But I still don't understand what the degenerate norm is?

Comment: By the homogeneity of the norm, this implies $\|v\|=0$ for all $v$ which is so degenerate as to be no norm at all. Similarly, $Av=o(\|v\|)$ implies $A=0$ which again leads to $\|v\|=o(\|v\|)$ or $1=\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{\|v\|}{\|v\|}=0$.

Comment: Do I need both conditions or is one sufficient? And I have $2||v|| = o(||v||)$ from the homogenity property.

Comment: One should be sufficient. But use the arguments that you can explain and defend.

Comment: What was the function in the argument?

Comment: Was it $f(x)=||v||?$